# How to represent complex class in an AbstractTableModel?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, abstracttablemodel

I have this class:

```
public abstract class Directory {

    protected int id;
    protected File path;
    protected LinkedList<Filter> filters;
    protected LinkedList<File> files;
    protected int wildcard;
    public static int numCols = 3;

    /* other things */
}
```

And I wrote this table model:

```
public class DirectoryListTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private LinkedList<Directory> datalist;
    private String[] columnNames= {"ID", "Directory", "Wildcard", "Filters"};


    public DirectoryListTableModel(){
    }

    public void setDatalist(LinkedList<Directory> temp){
        this.datalist = temp;
    }

    public void showElement(){
        fireTableRowsInserted(this.datalist.size()-2,this.datalist.size()-2);
    }

    public LinkedList<Directory> getDatalist(){
        return (LinkedList<Directory>) this.datalist.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return this.columnNames[column];    
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return Directory.numCols;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return this.datalist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {

        Directory temp = this.datalist.get(row);

        switch(col){
        case 0:
            return temp.getId();
        case 1:
            return temp.getPath();
        case 2:
            return temp.getWildcard();
        default:
            return null;        
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a `LinkedList<Filter>` that I would like too show as a simple string. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e.g.:

```
case 3:
    return temp.getFilters().toString();
```

Note:

- Use the interface (e.g. List) rather than the implementation (LinkedList) when declaring fields (if you don't have a good reason to do otherwise).
- ArrayList has a better performance than LinkedList in most cases (e.g. such as access by index)
- Also override getColumnClass
- Keep your fields private
- setDatalist: fireTableDataChanged

Comment: First of all, thank you. I need my fields protected because that's an abstract class. How do I override getColumnClass? I mean: should I return String.class if columnindex=3? Or LinkedList.class?

Comment: Then provide protected getters (and setters if needed)


Whatever getValueAt returns, so String.class in this case.

Comment: I'm using getters and setters. They're just left out because that class is really long.